# How should I verify whether pacman package install was successful?

Tags: package-management, arch-linux

What's the right way to ensure that a package installation with `pacman` has completed successfully when using `pacman` in a script?

During the recent repository outage of MSYS2, which uses `pacman`, I discovered that an installation with

```
pacman -S --noconfirm somepackage1 somepackage2
```

will still give an exit code of `0` despite not having installed the requested packages if it didn't attempt to install them because all dependent package download attempts timed out.

I've now added package queries after the supposed installation that definitely exit with `1` when the given package was not installed, which will take care of this exact case:

```
pacman -Qi somepackage
```

But I wonder if there are other types of package installation failure I don't know about that `pacman` also returns `0` for.

What's the right way to use `pacman` and definitely know whether it considers the package installation successful or not?